# Change only one select style in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

So I am using chosen - jquery plugin for selects.

Say I have four selects on the webpage, and I want the last one to open upward. I know how to change style to open select upward, but I can't figure out how to do this for only one select. It is probably trivial but I couldn't find the answer anywhere

To install it I downloaded files *chosen.jquery.min.js* as well as *chosen.css* and I put following code into my js file that handles all selects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').chosen({ width: '100%', disable_search_threshold: 9 });
});
```

I should probably add classes to selects, add style that I want to override to *chosen2.css*, right? But then how to connect those particular selects with new css file?

Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to accomplish:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmvLxdq9/)

Comment: Have you tried to use :last-child on the select classes? I don't know what classes 'chosen' uses to style the elements but I think you can do something like that. It would be easier to help if you provide a jsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**

I modified your fiddle, just put your last `select` inside a `div` and apply your css just to selects inside that div:

[Drop Up](https://codepen.io/mDEVnfe/pen/MWYVEKx)

```
<div class="drop-up">
  <div class="box" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 15px;">
    <select class="chosen-select">
        <option selected="selected">10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>100</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.drop-up .chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I am looking for - I edited my question, you can find fiddle there - as you can see both selects open upwards - 'last-of-type' doesn't work in this case

Comment: That's excatly what I was looking for! I knew there is some easy solution for this :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use classes or Ids on your select tag
for example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.last').chosen({ width: '100%', disable_search_threshold: 9 });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#last').chosen({ width: '100%', disable_search_threshold: 9 });
});
```

Comment: But they both point to the same 'chosen select', so they will still be the same in regards of style